# PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type in populating an associative array table

Tags: plsql

I have this structure of table in my database

[image]

Now i want all the values inside of it in a associative array that is indexed by the job_id%type which is a varchar2, so i created this anonymous block first before creating a procedure to test it and i want to populate my associative array with the results:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE jobs_tab_type IS TABLE OF jobs%rowtype INDEX BY jobs.job_id%type;
    jobstab jobs_tab_type;
BEGIN

    FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM jobs)
    LOOP
        jobstab(rec.job_id) := rec.job_id;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I know for sure that this is a wrong way to do it since I've encountered this error: **`PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type`** , but at the same time i don't know if there is any proper way to do this. I have seen the documentation but all the examples were to use a user defined string that will hold the job_id, but the problem is that i need the job_id to be indexed and not a user defined string. Is there any way to fix this problem in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *need* the index by `INDEX BY jobs.job_id%type`. It is making your code more complicated. The `INDEX BY` determines the *index* of the collection - that is the character used to indicate the position in the collection. That doesn't *need* to be a column from the table you are taking a %rowtype from.
Typically an `INDEX BY VARCHAR2` is used if you want to reference the collection based on a meaningful string, like `capitals('United States') = 'Washingston'`

Now, about your question. Here is the answer to the original question:

```
create table jobs
(job_id VARCHAR2(10)
,job_title VARCHAR2(30)
,min_salary NUMBER
,max_salary NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO jobs (job_id, job_title, min_salary, max_salary) VALUES ('a','CLERK',100,500);
INSERT INTO jobs (job_id, job_title, min_salary, max_salary) VALUES ('b','PRESIDENT',1000,5000);
INSERT INTO jobs (job_id, job_title, min_salary, max_salary) VALUES ('c','SALESMAN',500,800);

DECLARE
    TYPE jobs_tab_type IS TABLE OF jobs%rowtype INDEX BY jobs.job_id%type;
    jobstab jobs_tab_type;
    l_idx VARCHAR2(100);  
BEGIN

    FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM jobs)
    LOOP
        jobstab(rec.job_id) := rec;
    END LOOP;
    
    l_idx := jobstab.FIRST;     
    WHILE (l_idx IS NOT NULL) LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(l_idx ||': '||jobstab(l_idx).job_title);
      l_idx := jobstab.NEXT(l_idx);
    END LOOP;
END;
/

a: CLERK
b: PRESIDENT
c: SALESMAN
```

Notice that in this block, it's a bit tedious to loop through the elements, just because the index is not an integer. Now lets look at the same functionality, but using an `INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER`:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE jobs_tab_type IS TABLE OF jobs%rowtype INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    jobstab jobs_tab_type;
    l_idx NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN

-- example 1: using a cursor for loop

--    FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM jobs)
--    LOOP
--        jobstab(l_idx) := rec;
--        l_idx := l_idx + 1;
--    END LOOP;
    
-- example 2: using bulk collect
    SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO jobstab FROM jobs;
    
    FOR r IN 1 .. jobstab.COUNT LOOP
       dbms_output.put_line(r ||': '||jobstab(r).job_title);
    END LOOP;
END;
/


1: CLERK
2: PRESIDENT
3: SALESMAN
```

It's simpler to loop through the values of a collection because of the numeric index and it also can be implicitly assigned as well, using the `BULK COLLECT`  statement.

Answer (score 0):

The value of your associative array is the entire record. Hence just remove `.job_id` from this line of your code.

```sql
jobstab(rec.job_id) := rec.job_id;
```

In other words, the line should be

```sql
jobstab(rec.job_id) := rec;
```

Refer to [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9f3ff398f36c3e6530c265403af8aced)